# Angular params updated but page content not

Tags: angular, parameters

I have an angular App, I am in a url tasks/0 and I want to navigate to tasks/1, tasks/2 etc.

In task.component.html, I have a normal button:

```
  <a (click)="onNext()">
    Next
  </a>
```

I display some information regarding tasks:

```
<div class="task-wrapper">
  <div class="task-name">Name: {{ task.name }}</div>
  <div class="task-description">Description: {{ task.description }}</div>
</div>
```

I navigate to where I want to go (next Task Id)

task.component.ts

```
  onNext() {
    this.router.navigate(['../', this.currentTaskId + 1], {relativeTo: this.route});
  }
```

This is working because the url changes.

Unfortunately, the data is not changing. I subscribed to changes in params:

task.component.ts

```
this.route.params
      .subscribe(
        (params: Params) => {
          this.currentTaskId = +params.taskId;
          this.hackId = +params.hackId;
        }
      )
```

I have put console.logs in ngOnInit, and they are never triggered, except if I refresh the page. If I refresh the page, I have the right taskId (it was already in the url), and I see the right data.

Any help?

Complet component:

```
export class TaskDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  task: Task;
  currentTaskId: number;
  hack: Hack;
  hackId: number;
  isLastTask: boolean = false;
  isFirstTask: boolean = false;
  isVisitor: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private hackService: HackService,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ngOnInit aaaa")
    this.task = new Task({
      name: "",
      description: ""
    })

    this.hack = new Hack({});

    // in case refreshing
    this.route.params
      .subscribe(
        (params: Params) => {
          this.currentTaskId = +params.taskId;
          this.hackId = +params.hackId;
          this.hackService.hacksChanged.subscribe(
            hacks => {
              this.loadinfo(this.hackId, this.currentTaskId);
            }
          );
        }
      )

    // navigating from inside the app, not refreshing
    this.currentTaskId = +this.route.snapshot.params.taskId;
    console.log(this.currentTaskId);
    this.hackId = +this.route.snapshot.params.hackId;
    const hacks = this.hackService.getHacks();
    if (hacks) {
      this.loadinfo(this.hackId, this.currentTaskId);
    }
  }

  onNext() {
    this.router.navigate(['../', this.currentTaskId + 1], {relativeTo: this.route});
  }

  loadinfo(hackId: number, currentTaskId: number) {
    this.hack = this.hackService.getHack(this.hackId);
    this.task = this.hack.tasks[this.currentTaskId];
    const tasksLength = this.hack.tasks.length;
    this.isLastTask = this.currentTaskId === tasksLength - 1
    this.isFirstTask = this.currentTaskId === 0

    // check if user is visitor
    const loggedUserId = this.authService.getUid();
    const creatorUserId = this.route.snapshot.params.userId;
    this.isVisitor = creatorUserId !== loggedUserId 
  }
}
```

Comment: I see no data in what you have provided.

Comment: `this.router.params.subscribe` you are subscribing to route where as you're navigating through router either thats a typo also i dont see where the data is changed in the subscription ngOnInit is only triggered once on component load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only assume that you are fetching data in `onInit()`
You have to do that on params subscription

```
this.route.params
      .subscribe(
        (params: Params) => {
          this.currentTaskId = +params.taskId;
          this.hackId = +params.hackId;
          //invoke data fetch here insteed of onInit
          fetchDataLikeInOnInitYouDo()
        }
      )
```

Comment: yeah, problem was, inside the subscription of params, I had a subscription of hacks (in case user refreshes pages). Since hacks didn't change, I was never calling my loadInfo method. Thanks a lot

Comment: If that helped consider upvoting and/or accepting answer.